# MapReduce 2 job runs locally instead of being submitted to yarn

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

So i tried to configure my job to be submitted to yarn, but instead it runs locally:

```
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "ADDRESS:8032");
config.set("mapreduce.framework.name", "yarn"); 
config.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://ADDRESS:8020");
```

If i set **mapred.job.tracker** it fails with:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RpcServerException): Unknown rpc kind in rpc headerRPC_WRITABLE
```

because its not MR1.

So why is the app not submitted to yarn?

Comment: What is the command you are using to submit to job?

Comment: Do you have single node or multiple node cluster

Comment: @franklinsijo: im running a normal mapreduce job like:
Job job = new Job(config, "job");
.....
job.waitForCompletion(true)
 And the job starts running in my local eclipse instead of being submitted to yarn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by doing this:

```
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "ADDRESS:8032");
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address", "ADDRESS:8030");
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address", "ADDRESS:8031");
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address", "ADDRESS:8033");
```

instead of:

```
config.set("yarn.resourcemanager.address", "ADDRESS:8032");
```